# Map shell job numbers to PIDs

Tags: bash, job-control

I use shell job control to kick longer running tasks in to the background so I can continue while they churn through their data.

I can see the jobs I've got running with `jobs`, for example,

```
jobs
[2]-  Running                 su - root -c "..." &  (wd: /backup/rsnapshot)
[3]+  Running                 sleep 60 &
```

and I can control any one of these using the `%` *jobspec* syntax, such as `fg %su` or `kill %3`.

If I use `jobs -l` I get the PIDs too:

```
jobs -l
[2]- 31736 Running                 su - root -c "..." &  (wd: /backup/rsnapshot)
[3]+  2269 Running                 sleep 60 &
```

Using `bash` I've got `jobs -x`, but this [isn't POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/jobs.html). Is this the only way to translate these `%` *jobspec* values into PIDs, or is there a sensible (better) alternative approach? What about for other shells?

```
jobs -x echo %3
2269
```

My target use case is for the `%` *jobspec* to be expanded *transparently* on the command line into the corresponding PID, so that in a command such as this the `%2` would be seen by the command as `31736`

```
pidtree %2    # pidtree 31736
```

This can be handled as `jobs -x pidtree %2` but that's not as elegant or convenient.

I'd like at least one answer targeting `bash`, but contributions for other shells with job control are welcome, particularly if you have a POSIX solution.

Comment: `jobs -l` or `jobs -x` can be piped to a bash action to get informations over the job like openned files & so on ; depending of your final objectives . for example `cat  /proc/25943/task/25943/statm` and so on... Please edit the question with an use case.

Comment: tried out an example : `cat /proc/$(jobs -l | sed 's/.*+ \(.*\) [A-Z].*/\1/; /[^0-9]/ d  ')/statm` answered `2451 1109 398 219 0 742 0` so sed substitution worked (_not optimized at all to let you understand_)

Comment: `jobs -l` or `jobs -x` is part of the Bourne Shell since before bash exists. Is your question about non-conforming shells?

Comment: I suspect that roaima's _next_ question will be what part of the SVID talks about `jobs -x`, because the SUS does not.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP Thanks for the hint. It is in the Boune Shell and  I thought it would be in the Korn Shell but it is not. This is really strange. Well, the Bourne Shell is a nice shell for interactive use nowerdays.

Comment: @roaima, I suppose parsing the output isn't an option? Something like `jobs -l | perl -lne '/\[(\d+)\][-+]?\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S.*)/; print "jobID:$1\tPID:$2\tstate:$3\tcomm:$4"'`?

Comment: @schily `jobs -x` wasn't recognised by `dash` and it's [not POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/jobs.html)

Comment: @francoisP use case added. Basically it's interactive use where I want the `%` _jobspec_ to be translated (transparently if possibly) to the PID

Answer (score 2):

On `bash` you might get close to that by providing a custom `$PROMPT_COMMAND` setting variables on-fly from the current list of jobs.

Proof-of-concept:

```bsh
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='unset ${!j*}; eval "$(jobs -l | awk '\''{gsub("[^[:digit:] ]", ""); printf "j%d=%d\n", $1, $2}'\'')"'
```

You would then do `pidtree $j2` instead of `pidtree %2`, assuming there are no numbers in `$IFS` or else you have to quote the `$j2` thus requiring two keystrokes more.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this for a few commands only, then programmable completion would be an option. That is most probably not POSIX but at least available in several shells (and the underlying mechanism would not even have to be the same).

So you would type `pidtree %2`<kbd>Tab</kbd> and the shell would transform that into

```
pidtree 31736
```

I would consider that as elegant and convenient.

Disadvantage: Keeping existing completion configurations for those commands requires manual intervention (like: run your function first; if it does not match then make it call the original one).

```
_pidtree () {
    local job pid
    if [[ ${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]} =~ ^%[1-9][0-9]* ]]; then
        job="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]:1}"
        pid="$(jobs -l | awk -v job="$job" '$1 ~ "^\\[" job "\\]" { print $2; }')"
        COMPREPLY=("$pid")
    fi
}

complete -F _pidtree pidtree
```

That works in `bash`. It could be done without `awk`, and it certainly can be done in a more compatible way.

Jobs which contain newlines could be a problem but as this is your interactive shell there seems not to be a risk that this could be exploited.

Comment: Are you saying this is already a thing, or that you're suggesting it as an unimplemented possibility? I like this

Comment: I did not search for something like that but doubt that it is well known available. I added some code to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easiest to just remember the PIDs when the backgroud jobs are created?

`bash`:

```
declare -a bgjobpids
[...]
do_some_thing &
pid=$!
index=${#bgjobpids[@]}
bgjobpids[index]=$pid
[...]
do_some_thing_else &
pid=$!
index=${#bgjobpids[@]}
bgjobpids[index]=$pid
```

Comment: Programmatically, yes sure. But my use case is the interactive shell